# How does Moonbeam work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, area-of-effect

So, I saw a similar question explaining that Moonbeam and other similar hazard spells don't deal damage when they attack. However, since moonbeam is able to be moved, are the enemies considered 'entering' the spells AOE when it moves on to the tile they are standing on (if it comes to rest there)? The other answers and the wording lead me to believe that it could go either way, so I am curious to get some of your opinions.

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: As a note for future and/or clarifying your question; you should probably link to the question you're referring to, so it's clearer what you've read and what the question's context is.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Thanks. That post answered my question exactly.